# LINQ Where clause with four &&

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to create an LINQ Query with 4 arguments in the Where clause. It's a Windows 8 App project and I'm using an SQLite Database. ([SQLite implementation](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) )

Here's the code snippet:

```
public List<FinancialListBoxExpenseItem> retrieveExpenseItems(int month, int year, bool isPaid, StaticResources.FrequencyEnum frequencyEnum)
{
    List<FinancialListBoxExpenseItem> tmpList = null;

    connection.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        var items = from s in connection.Table<FinancialListBoxExpenseItem>()
                    where (s.expenseDateNextPayment.Month == month)
                       && (s.expenseDateNextPayment.Year == year)
                       && (s.expensePaidForCurrentPeriod == isPaid)
                       && (s.expenseFrequencyTypeEnum == frequencyEnum)
                    select s;
        tmpList = items.ToList<FinancialListBoxExpenseItem>();
    });

    return tmpList;
}
```

It throws a NotSupportedAction: Member access failed to compile expression Exception

I have no idea what does this mean and how i'm supposed to fix it.

Edit: **it works without the where clause** therefore the error must be related to this where clause part of the code

Comment: Just speculating here, but does it throw if you leave off the last element of the where? Every other expression in your where clause is a basic type so wondering if it can't handle the enum.  If so, perhaps convert to string?

Comment: i tried it without the enum but i doesen't work either.
i even tried it with only one condition in the where clause but with no luck, still got the same exception

Comment: What if it will be no where clause?

Comment: it works without the where clause therefore the error must be related to this where clause part of the code

Comment: check if something in the where condition is null, you might be getting this error because of that.

Comment: @Mayank: I don't think so, i couldn't check 's' but the method variables are definitely not null. But during my debugging session i figured out that the Exception occurs not in the where clause. The exception is thrown by the following line of code: tmpList = items.ToList<FinancialListBoxExpenseItem>();

Comment: have you tried `....select s.ToList();`

Comment: 's' has the type FinancialListBoxExpenseItem and does not offer a ToList() method. Or do you mean "tmpList = items.ToList();"? i tried both but without luck.

Comment: Try adding each part of the where clause one by one to see which fails and update your question with the result. Probably one of the constructs used is not supported by the SQLite LINQ provider (I would guess the .Year and .Month stuff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how i solved the problem:

```
public List<FinancialListBoxExpenseItem> retrieveExpenseItems(int month, int year, bool isPaid, StaticResources.FrequencyEnum frequencyEnum)
{
    List<FinancialListBoxExpenseItem> tmpList = new List<FinancialListBoxExpenseItem>();

    connection.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        var items = from s in connection.Table<FinancialListBoxExpenseItem>()
                    let convertedDate = (DateTime)s.expenseDateNextPayment
                    where (convertedDate.Month == month)
                       && (convertedDate.Year == year)
                       && (s.expensePaidForCurrentPeriod == isPaid)
                       && (s.expenseFrequencyTypeEnum == frequencyEnum)
                    select s;
        tmpList = items.ToList();
    });

    return tmpList;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably `.Month` is not supported by your LINQ provider. You'll have to work around that, possibly by creating specialized columns for the month and the year.

Comment: Yeah... Linq and date don't always play well together.

Comment: it works without "month" and "year" in the where clause! But i don't understand why because expenseDateNextPayment is an DateTime object and expenseDateNextPayment.Month returns an int value.

Is there a common solution to this problem? Do i really have to add additional columns (for month an year) to the database?

Comment: Only those features which the LINQ provider supports to translate to SQL are supported. If the SQLite provider does not understand DateTime.Month it cannot translate to SQL.

Comment: @usr: thank you for putting me into the right direction! This is how i solved the problem: `...let convertedDate = (DateTime)s.expenseDateNextPayment
                    where (convertedDate.Month == month)
                       && (convertedDate.Year == year)...`

Answer (score 0):

In my App I was getting a `NotSupportedException` when running a LINQ query, and the details of the exception showed

> Member access failed to compile expression

As this thread let me know, the issued seemed to be caused by a `DateTime` variable that was being referenced in the query.  Outside of finding a StackOverflow thread like this one to point you in the right direction, I'm not sure how anyone is supposed to figure that out on their own, but for me, changing the way I was writing the query fixed the problem.

This syntax was throwing the "NotSupportedException":*

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = connection.Table<Foo>().Where(foo => foo.Timestamp.Year == year);
```

Switching to this syntax worked just fine:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = connection.Table<Foo>().Where(
    delegate(Foo foo)
{
    return (foo.Timestamp.Year == year);
});
```