# SQL to LINQ Query with date in where clause is not working

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, linq-to-sql, sqlite-net

I try to query database item via LINQ but it is not working. The exception is just:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The stacktrace is as unhelpful as the exception itself:

> at SQLite.TableQuery`1.CompileExpr(Expression expr, List`1
>   queryArgs) in d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\SQLite.cs:line 2383    at
>   SQLite.TableQuery`1.CompileExpr(Expression expr, List`1 queryArgs) in
>   d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\SQLite.cs:line 2388    at
>   SQLite.TableQuery`1.CompileExpr(Expression expr, List`1 queryArgs) in
>   d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\SQLite.cs:line 2308    at
>   SQLite.TableQuery`1.CompileExpr(Expression expr, List`1 queryArgs) in
>   d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\SQLite.cs:line 2308    at
>   SQLite.TableQuery`1.CompileExpr(Expression expr, List`1 queryArgs) in
>   d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\SQLite.cs:line 2308    at
>   SQLite.TableQuery`1.GenerateCommand(String selectionList) in
>   d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\SQLite.cs:line 2274    at
>   SQLite.TableQuery`1.GetEnumerator() in
>   d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\SQLite.cs:line 2521    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Kapital.DataModel.DataManagerOnetimeExpense.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4()
>   in d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\DataModel\DataManagerOnetimeExpense.cs:line 47
>   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.RunInTransaction(Action action) in
>   d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\SQLite.cs:line 906    at
>   Kapital.DataModel.DataManagerOnetimeExpense.RetrieveItems(Int32 month,
>   Int32 year, Boolean isPaid) in
>   d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\DataModel\DataManagerOnetimeExpense.cs:line 39    at
>   UnitTestKapital.Database.TestDataManagerOnetimeExpense.TestRetrieveItemsByMonthYearIsPaid()
>   in
>   d:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\UnitTestKapital\Database\TestDataManagerOnetimeExpense.cs:line
>   154

However here is the LINQ query:

```
public List<OnetimeExpense> RetrieveItems(int month, int year, bool isPaid)
{
    var onetimeExpenses = new List<OnetimeExpense>();

    connection.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        var items = from s in connection.Table<OnetimeExpense>()
                    let convertedDate = (DateTime)s.PaymentDate
                    where (convertedDate.Month == month)
                       && (convertedDate.Year == year)
                       && (s.IsPaid == isPaid)
                    select s;
        onetimeExpenses = items.ToList();
    });

    return onetimeExpenses;
}
```

It has definitely something todo with the date because the following method is working (basically the same method without the date stuff):

```
public List<OnetimeExpense> RetrieveItems(bool isPaid)
{
    var onetimeExpenses = new List<OnetimeExpense>();

    connection.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        var items = from s in connection.Table<OnetimeExpense>()
                    where (s.IsPaid == isPaid)
                    select s;
        onetimeExpenses = items.ToList();
    });

    return onetimeExpenses;
}
```

And here comes the fun part: I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542558/linq-where-clause-with-four) a few month ago with an WinRT Application. I managed to solve this the same way as shown above.

I'm using [SQLite 3.7.16.2](http://www.sqlite.org/). The LINQ Provider is [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).

What else? Visual Studio 2012, C#, .Net 4.5. It is an WPF Application.

**Edit:**
Here is my Data Object, its a simple POCO. PaymentDate is initialized with DateTime.Today and therefore never null.

```
public class OnetimeExpense : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /**
     * int Id
     * string Name
     * DateTime PaymentDate
     * decimal Amount
     * Boolean IsPaid
     * */
    #region getters and setters

    private int id;
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            this.id = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    private DateTime paymentDate = DateTime.Today;
    public DateTime PaymentDate
    {
        get { return this.paymentDate; }
        set
        {
            paymentDate = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("PaymentDate");
        }
    }

    private bool isPaid;
    public bool IsPaid
    {
        get { return this.isPaid; }
        set
        {
            this.isPaid = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsPaid");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public OnetimeExpense(string name, decimal amount, DateTime paymentDate, bool isPaid)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.isPaid = isPaid;
    }

    public OnetimeExpense()
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

---

**Edit2**
Gert Arnold suggested to use this **work around**. It is working and has as far as i understood a better performance than my query. Nevertheless, i would like to know whats wrong with the query above.

```
public List<OnetimeExpense> RetrieveItems(int month, int year, bool isPaid)
{
    var onetimeExpenses = new List<OnetimeExpense>();

    var lowerBound = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    var upperBound = lowerBound.AddMonths(1);

    connection.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        var items = from s in connection.Table<OnetimeExpense>()
                    where s.PaymentDate >= lowerBound
                       && s.PaymentDate < upperBound
                       && s.IsPaid == isPaid
                    select s;
        onetimeExpenses = items.ToList();
    });

    return onetimeExpenses;
}
```

Comment: In each of the two queries, how many results should be in items?

Comment: Is `PaymentDate` a nullable DateTime column? If so, there could be a problem casting a null value to DateTime?

Comment: maybe check s.PaymentDate for null, something like `where ((convertedDate != null ? convertedDate.Month : null) == month)...`

Comment: @MikePrecup: tried it with an empty database and with some test data (about 20 entries) got the same exception both times.

Comment: @TI and Netricity: i will recheck tomorrow but i'm pretty sure that s.PaymentDate is not null. Have a look at my DataModel there you can see that PaymentDate is initialized with DateTime.Today; The other parameters (month, year and isPaid) are also not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct solution, but you can circumvent the issue by filtering differently. Suppose you want to filter records for May, 2013:

```
var lowerBound = new DateTime(2013,5,1);
var upperBound = new DateTime(2013,6,1);

var items = from s in connection.Table<OnetimeExpense>()
            where s.PaymentDate >= lowerBound
               && s.PaymentDate < upperBound
               && s.IsPaid == isPaid
            select s;
```

This is more than just evading the issue. It also has the potential of making the query more efficient when there is an index on `PaymentDate`. Expressions like `convertedDate.Year` are translated to `DATEPART(Year, [t0].[PaymentDate])`. Such expressions are not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), i.e. the database engine can't use an index for lookup.

Comment: sounds good, i will give it a try and come back to you. i was not aware about sargable or non-sargable queries thank you for this.

Comment: Your query is working, thank you. But nevertheless i would like to understand why my query is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (LoggingFilter.StartDate.HasValue)
            {
                logs = auditlogs.Where(x => x.DateTime > auditLoggingFilter.StartDate).ToList();
            }
            if (LoggingFilter.EndDate.HasValue)
            {
                LoggingFilter.EndDate = LoggingFilter.EndDate.Value.AddTicks(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Ticks);
                logs = auditlogs.Where(x => x.DateTime < LoggingFilter.EndDate).ToList();
            }
```

This works for me.